# Django: resize images with different width/height ratios

Tags: python, html, django

For a page showing many pictures I use something like

```
<img src='{{ instance.piece_image.url }}' hspace='40' vspace='40' style='width:16%;height:16%;'/>
```

or

```
<img src='{{ instance.piece_image.url }}' hspace='40' vspace='40' width='250px' height='250px'/>
```

However, my images have different width/height ratios and differ in absolute size (allowing more flexibility for the user uploading the image). Now the first method keeps the aspect ratio while not respecting the absolute size of the image whereas the second method fixes the absolute size but does not accommodate for different aspect ratios.
**What would be the preferred way to resize my images keeping the aspect ratio and and providing a fixed absolute size (of the greater of width or height)?**
E.g. it could be achieved by recalculating the width and height with basic math but I did not find a convenient way to do this in a template yet.

Comment: try `max-width`, `min-width`, etc. eg- `width: 20%; min-width: 200px;`.

Comment: seems to get the job done, thanks @psinaught! Feel free to post it as answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

try `max-width`, `min-width`, etc. eg- `width: 20%; min-width: 200px;`.

Here `max-width` etc. will make sure that image is not too small or big while `width` in percentage will make the image as responsive as possible within limits imposed by `max-width` etc.

Comment: Welcome. While this answer may be correct it is good practice to provide detailed explanations for your answer. This will help the poster and others to understand the solution.